# The operator * is undefined for the argument type(s) int, String / Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to int

Tags: java, integer, double, operators, type-mismatch

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Asgn1 {

```
//comment practice
/*multi-line comment practice
* no text fill
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //user prompted inputs for future calculations
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("The following information is required:");
    System.out.println("Enter customer ID: ");
    String customerId = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter unit price in decimal format (up to two decimals, e.g. 3.5): ");
    String unitPrice = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter quantity (whole numbers only): ");
    String orderQuantity = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter product description, (e.g. 'whole wheat bread'): ");
    String productDescription = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter discount in decimal format (e.g. .05 = 5%): ");
    String appliedDiscount = in.nextLine();

    //confirm order data details and display to user
    System.out.println("Your order data is as follows: ");
    System.out.println("Customer ID: " + customerId);
    System.out.println("Unit Price: " + unitPrice);
    System.out.println("Order Quantity: " + orderQuantity );
    System.out.println("Product Description: " +  productDescription);
    System.out.println("Applied Discount: " + appliedDiscount);

    //calculation formulas based on users input
    int beforeDiscount = (Integer.parseInt(unitPrice) * Integer.parseInt(orderQuantity));
    int afterDiscount = 1 - (Integer.parseInt(unitPrice) * Integer.parseInt(orderQuantity)) * (appliedDiscount);
    
    //totals before and after discount
    System.out.println("Your Order Totals");
    System.out.println("Before Discount: ");
    System.out.println("After Discount: ");

}
```

}

I have this java code I want to take the unit price and multiply that by the order quantity, then apply the discount so I can display a before and after discount price.

Originally, when I entered this, I figured out I had to parse the strings for unitPrice and orderQuantity as ints, but when I tried that with the double, I got this message as well on the same line: "Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to int".

I tried looking around at other answers but could not find something that would fix this issue so I'm asking for help, please. What would be the best way to solve this?

In the future, should I try to alter it before it comes in, maybe where they input it, or do I wait until I get the values and then alter that? What would convention dictate?

Thank you for your consideration and assistance.

Comment: `String appliedDiscount`  so `* (appliedDiscount)` is a no no

Comment: `"Enter unit price in decimal format (up to two decimals, e.g. 3.5): "` so why try to convert to an `int` ?  Convert to a `float`

Comment: As well as writing either `Double.parseDouble(appliedDiscount)` or `Float.parseFloat(appliedDiscount)`, you'll need to change the data type at the start of that same line to either `float` or `double`.  Otherwise you're trying to assign a number with decimal parts to an `int` variable.

Comment: Thanks, guys, this is good stuff to know. I appreciate the assistance.

Answer (score 1):

I change some things on the code... first, the type of variables of unit price and appliedDiscount into double. And also I change the formula to calculate price after discount.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //user prompted inputs for future calculations
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner in2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("The following information is required:");
    System.out.println("Enter customer ID: ");
    String customerId = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter unit price in decimal format (up to two decimals, e.g. 3.5): ");
    double unitPrice = in.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter quantity (whole numbers only): ");
    int orderQuantity = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter product description, (e.g. 'whole wheat bread'): ");
    String productDescription = in2.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter discount in decimal format (e.g. .05 = 5%): ");
    double appliedDiscount = in.nextDouble();
    //confirm order data details and display to user
    System.out.println("Your order data is as follows: ");
    System.out.println("Customer ID: " + customerId);
    System.out.println("Unit Price: " + unitPrice);
    System.out.println("Order Quantity: " + orderQuantity );
    System.out.println("Product Description: " +  productDescription);
    System.out.println("Applied Discount: " + appliedDiscount);

    //calculation formulas based on users input
    double beforeDiscount = (unitPrice * orderQuantity);
    double afterDiscount = beforeDiscount - (beforeDiscount * (appliedDiscount));
    //totals before and after discount
    System.out.println("Your Order Totals" );
    System.out.println("Before Discount: "+  beforeDiscount);
    System.out.println("After Discount: " + afterDiscount);
```

}

Comment: Angela, thank you very much. I noticed you also added a new scanner, in2. If I may ask, what does that do? Thanks again for your assistance.